# PHP Help for Echoing Variables

Tags: php, echo

I'm a beginner in writing PHP, but working on developing themes in WordPress.

I have no idea how to echo my `style` option within my front-page.php.

My meta.php:

```
$meta_style = array();

$meta_style['meta_style'] = array(
    'dash_icon' => 'list-view',
    'title' =>  __('Section Settings', 'fluent'),
    'description' => __('These are general section settings.','fluent'),
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'option_name' => 'meta_style',
    'caps' => array(),
    'fields' => array(
        'style' => array(
            //...
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array(//option value = option label
                'value' => 'white',
                'value2' => 'black'
            ),
            'multiple' => false,//allow multiple values to be selected - default false
            'placeholder' => 'white'//placeholder text for the element
        ),
    ),
);
```

My `front-page.php` (it's wrapped in a BUTTON just a see if the variable echoes):

```
<button>
    <? if($meta = get_post_meta($post->ID)){ if($meta['style'] == true){ echo $meta['value']; } } ?>
</button>
```

Can anyone provide an additional examples on how to echo other types, such as `'type' => 'text'`?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what you want, but you should:

1 - See if you're echoing the right information

2 - Use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Answer (score 0):

In your first code example you have a variable `$meta_style` which is a map. It has one key, `'meta_style'` that leads to a next map. Inside that inner map you have the keys `'dash_icon'` and so on. So for example this should echo the string `'normal'`:

```
echo $meta_style['meta_style']['context'];
```

However, in your second example, you have a variable `$meta` which is also a map, having keys `'style'` and `'value'`. You could echo those with:

```
echo $meta['style'];
echo $meta['value'];
```

Based on your example, I have no idea what these should do or how they should be related, or what their meaning should be.